# TD contenteditable and update value in database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, contenteditable

I have a table which i make the td's contenteditable, for the user to easily input the data needed.

Every rows and td have value of null in database. It will have value when the user will input something and it will save/update when button save is click

my php for tbody :

```
 <?php
$emp_name = $_SESSION["emp_name"];
$month = $_SESSION["month"];
$REMARKS = $_SESSION[""];
$date_now = date('m');
$current_day = date('d');
$sample_var=  $_SESSION["username"] ;

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=******;', '****', '*****' );
            $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
                " SELECT * from tbl_assessment WHERE employeeName = '{$_SESSION['emp_name']}' "
        );
        $flag = $stmt->execute();
        if ( !$flag ) {
            $info = $stmt->errorInfo();
            exit( $info[2] );
        }
        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

                @$tbody1 .='<tr>';
                    $tbody1 .=' <input type="hidden" id="id" value="'.$_SESSION['id'].'"/> ';
                    $tbody1 .=' <input type="hidden" id="emp_name" value="'.$_SESSION['emp_name'].'"/> ';
                    $tbody1 .=' <input type="hidden" id="teamCode" value="'.$_SESSION['teamCode'].'"/> ';
                    $tbody1 .=' <input type="hidden" id="sectionCode" value="'.$_SESSION['sectionCode'].'"/> ';


                    $tbody1 .='<td style="height:30px" contenteditable>'.$row["date"].'</td>';
                    $tbody1 .='<td style="height:30px" contenteditable>'.$row["staffName"].'</td>';
                    $tbody1 .='<td style="height:30px" contenteditable>'.$row["findings"].'</td>';
                    $tbody1 .='<td style="height:30px" contenteditable>'.$row["action"].'</td>';
                    $tbody1 .='<td style="height:30px" contenteditable>'.$row["date_accomplished"].'</td>';
                    $tbody1 .='<td><button class="btn btn-warning px-2" id="btnSaveFindings" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;" title="Save"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button class="btn btn-info px-2" id="btnEdit" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;" title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>';


        @$tbody .='</tr>';
        }   
            }
        catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $pdo = null;
        }   
?>
```

my html for table :

```
<div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:white;border-bottom:3px solid #ff6600;margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;margin-bottom:140px;" class="animated fadeInUp">
    <div class=""  style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;overflow-x:auto;" ><br>
        <button class="btn btn-default px-3" style="float:right;" id="btnAddRow" name="btnAddRow" title="Add New row"><i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <table class="assessment" id="assessment" width="1526px" >
        <thead style="background:-moz-linear-gradient( white, gray);">
            <tr>    
                <th colspan="6" style="font-size:20px;">ASSESSMENT/FINDINGS:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!---FIRST TABLE ROW--->
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>NAME OF THE STAFF/S</th>
                <th>ASSESSMENT/FINDINGS</th>
                <th>ACTION TAKEN</th>
                <th>DATE ACCOMPLISHED</th>
                <th>ACTION</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <?php echo $tbody1; ?>
            </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table><br><br>
</div>
```

what would be the function of `btnSaveFindings` to update the value of td in database?

Comment: pls I hope someone can help me with this..

Comment: You can try jquery and ajax to get it working as you can use event like on keyup or you check when the enter key is pressed then run ajax and pass all those values there and then do the update query.

Comment: What is the table-structure of your `tbl_assessment` table?

Comment: What **exactly** are you asking for? What have you tried to find an answer to your question, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note,

1. Your query is not using a prepared statement - which is very simple with PDO; suggest you use that!
2. Your loop can generate multiple HTML elements with the same ID - this violates the uniqueness of an ID - if something can have the same ID, it can probably be a class instead.
3. When printing large blocks of HTML, its often better to exit PHP mode to print it where you need it.
4. To update the table, use jQuery with AJAX - assign classes to the different `<td>` elements, so we can fetch them with jQuery, and when you click the button, find the closest values of that row. Add a rows unique identifier to a `data-*` attribute of the button, so we know which row to update.

```php
<?php
$emp_name = $_SESSION["emp_name"];
$month = $_SESSION["month"];
$REMARKS = $_SESSION[""];
$date_now = date('m');
$current_day = date('d');
$sample_var = $_SESSION["username"] ;

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=******;charset=utf8mb4', '****', '*****' );
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_assessment WHERE employeeName = :employeeName");
    $stmt->execute(['employeeName' => $_SESSION['emp_name']]);
    ?>
    <script>
        $(".btnSaveFindings").on("click", function() {
            var id = $(this).data('assessment-id'),
                row = $(this).closest("tr"),
                date = $(row).find('.assessment-date')[0],
                staffname = $(row).find('.assessment-staffname')[0],
                findings = $(row).find('.assessment-findings')[0],
                action = $(row).find('.assessment-action')[0],
                accomplished = $(row).find('.assessment-date-accomplished')[0];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "updateRow.php",
                data: {id: id,
                           date: date,
                       staffname: staffname,
                       findings: findings,
                       action: action,
                       accomplished: accomplished},
                success: function(data) {
                    var status = data.status,
                        message = data.message;

                   alert(message);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:white;border-bottom:3px solid #ff6600;margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;margin-bottom:140px;" class="animated fadeInUp">
        <div class=""  style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;overflow-x:auto;" ><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default px-3" style="float:right;" id="btnAddRow" name="btnAddRow" title="Add New row"><i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <table class="assessment" id="assessment" width="1526px" >
                <thead style="background:-moz-linear-gradient( white, gray);">
                    <tr>    
                        <th colspan="6" style="font-size:20px;">ASSESSMENT/FINDINGS:</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> <!---FIRST TABLE ROW--->
                        <th>DATE</th>
                        <th>NAME OF THE STAFF/S</th>
                        <th>ASSESSMENT/FINDINGS</th>
                        <th>ACTION TAKEN</th>
                        <th>DATE ACCOMPLISHED</th>
                        <th>ACTION</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php 
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height:30px" class="assessment-date" contenteditable><?php echo $row["date"] ?></td>
                                <td style="height:30px" class="assessment-staffname" contenteditable><?php echo $row["staffName"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="height:30px" class="assessment-findings" contenteditable><?php echo $row["findings"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="height:30px" class="assessment-action" contenteditable><?php echo $row["action"]; ?></td>
                                <td style="height:30px" class="assessment-date-accomplished" contenteditable><?php echo $row["date_accomplished"]; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning px-2 btnSaveFindings" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;" title="Save" data-assessment-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                                        <i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-info px-2 btnEdit" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;" title="Edit">
                                        <i class="fas fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    <?php 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo "An error occurred";
}
```

Then you need to create the file `updateRow.php` that runs the query.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=******;charset=utf8mb4', '****', '*****' );
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

// See that the POST is sent
if (empty($_POST)) {
    echo json_encode(['status' = false, 'message' => 'No data was sent. Update aborted']);
    exit;
}

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_assessment 
                           SET date = :date,
                               staffName = :staffName,
                               findings = :findings,
                               action = :action,
                               date_accomplished = :date_accomplished 
                            WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(['date' => $_POST['date'],
                    'staffName' => $_POST['staffName'],
                    'findings ' => $_POST['findings'],
                    'action ' => $_POST['action'],
                    'date_accomplished ' => $_POST['date_accomplished'],
                    'id ' => $_POST['id']]);

    echo json_encode(['status' = true, 'message' => 'Update completed.']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode(['status' = false, 'message' => 'An error occurred. Update failed.']);
}
```

As a final note, its often way better to use CSS classes on elements instead of inline styling. Makes for cleaner code, and more repeatable code.